# MYSQL How to insert image to database

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am using MySQL workbench and having some problems adding image to it. [Image of creating the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dbKR.png)
[Image of displayed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Bu5.png)

This is my what i did
however, when i say select * from products; I get a long text instead of actual image.

[image of table on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMSEm.jpg)

Comment: Can you be more specific than "having some problems"?  What exactly is the issue?  How are you saving the image?  Are you getting an error?  Unexpected behavior?  Something else?

Comment: If this is for a website, it's a lot easier to store the images normally on the server, and simply store the path to each image in a database.

Comment: Browsers do not support image viewing. You can pull the binary out of the database and convert it to an image when you need it.

Comment: @johnelemans how could i do that on workbench?

Comment: The answer is "don't", especially if it's "large". This will bloat your database and is generally a very inefficient way of doing things.

Comment: Workbench won't do it. You can only do it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment by Major Productions and John elemans make sense. I would not recommend storing image in SQL.

Just store the name of the image file such as 'pic.jpg' as a text in SQL. Combine the folder path later. For example, '/home/usr/picFolder/' + 'pic.jpg'

If you have to store it in binary, then the programming language you are using should have built-in function to convert binary to image.

Comment: Don't forget to rename the image filename to something *guaranteed* to be harmless. Someone could try and upload `evilfile.exe` or `../../../index.php` and you don't want it to stomp your code.